# Trying to install ffmpeg with brew and I keep getting errors related to "dav1d_bottle_manifest"

Tags: macos, installation, ffmpeg, homebrew, signal-processing

I am trying to do some basic DSP in python and in order to play some of my audio files I need to install ffmpeg on my computer.

I am running a 2019 macbook pro.

When I run brew intsall ffmpeg -d

I get this on my terminal output

```
rm: /usr/local/Homebrew/.git/TMP_FETCH_FAILURES: is a directory
rm: /usr/local/Homebrew/.git/TMP_FETCH_FAILURES: is a directory
Running `brew update --auto-update`...
```

This auto update just runs forever with no updates of any kind. I'm not sure if it is broken or stuck or what.

I try to manually run:

```
 brew update -d
```

and the update stalls forever on this section:

```
+ [[ -f /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/.git/FETCH_HEAD ]]
+ touch /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/.git/FETCH_HEAD
+ [[ -z '' ]]
+ [[ 200 == \3\0\4 ]]
+ [[ -n '' ]]
+ local tmp_failure_file=/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/.git/TMP_FETCH_FAILURES
+ rm -f /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/.git/TMP_FETCH_FAILURES
+ [[ -n '' ]]
+ git fetch --tags --force -q origin refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
```

I am having so many problems with brew any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated to the most recent version of MacOS then updated brew again and it worked this time. It appears that ffmpeg is working now in my code. Now it is just up to debugging other issues.